# Windows XP : How to Get USB device location from the disk drive letter

Tags: c++, windows, usb

When we connect USB mass storage device, two entries are created in the Device Manager: one under Disk Drive and another under USB as USB Mass Storage.

```
 HDEVINFO hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(
                (LPGUID) &GUID_DEVCLASS_DISKDRIVE,      // USB Device Class
                NULL,
                NULL, 
                DIGCF_PRESENT);
```

This will list the entry under Disk Drive

```
 HDEVINFO hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(
                (LPGUID) &GUID_DEVCLASS_USB,        // USB Device Class
                NULL,
                NULL,
                DIGCF_PRESENT);
```

This will list all the USB devices.

Is there any way to map the entries obtained from the above two calls.
I checked for device instance id of all the devices using `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo`,
but ids did not match

The reason I need to map these two entries is because I have to get the USB device location (Hub and Port) number

Thanks
Praveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drive letter is associated with a volume/partition on the drive. You'll see this when you use the "safe disconnect" option in Windows, where it will list all the entities that will be removed.

[So, check the device parent.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541087(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could enumerate physical disk devices using the GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK.  Using:

```
SetupDiGetClassDevs
(
    &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE
)
```

Then, query the storage adapter descriptor.

```
STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY storageProperty;
//...setup
PSTORAGE_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTOR pstorageAdapterDesc;
pstorageAdapterDesc = (PSTORAGE_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTOR)LocallAlloc( LPTR, storageDescHeader.Size );

DeviceIoControl
(
    handle,
    IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
    &storageProperty, 
    sizeof( STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY ),
    pstorageAdapterDesc,
    storageDescHeader.Size,
    bytesReturned,
    NULL
)
```

In the descriptor, you could use the "BusType" and check for USB.